# Install wordpress as a development site in a subdirectory on live server

Tags: 404-error, directory, installation

I am trying to set up a development environment for a friend. I have never had a problem before until now.

Basically on the home directory of the server there is a WordPress installation. My friend wants a new folder on the server called development.

So the Dev url would be mysite.com/development/

But when I try to install WordPress by going to the url /development/wp-admin/install.php I get a 404 with the live wordpress theme.

I cannot for the life in me figure out why it is doing this.

There is only the main WP info in the htaccess file and there are no plugins activated to prevent the install in the development folder.

I can visit html and txt files in the development folder but not php files. (readme/liecense etc)

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried using a **subdomain** (`dev.example.com`) rather than a **subfolder** (`example.com/dev`)?

Comment: yes, sadly I get the same problem. doesn't seem to want to play either way :-/